# C# Windows Form label font size

Tags: c#, winforms

I am coding in C# using Visual Studio and I am new to windows forms. I have just set a label. I'm trying to change the text size of the label but I can't find an option anywhere. Can someone tell me where I can find the option in the designer? If I can't do it in the designer where do I put the code when using the default set up?

I have been looking for about an hour and it appears as though I should use something like:

```
YourLabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 24,FontStyle.Bold);
```

Although, when I have modified the code to suit my needs, it doesn't seem to affect the windows form.

Here I have included a screenshot of my project layout.
[image: ProjectLayout]

Thanks!

Comment: write that code on mainForm_Load event and check

Comment: its probably silently causing an exception where you are, as the control doesnt exist yet.

Comment: Oh brilliant! That worked thanks <3

Comment: You can also write the code after IntializeComponent();

Answer (score 2):

Font size of a label can changed via properties window.

If you can not find the properties window, go to `View > Properties window`.

- Highlight the label then go to properties box and Find the "Font" and expand it.
- Under Font you can now find the "size" property.
- Default font size size is `8.25` which you can change as per your requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your form in *design* mode, then select label you want to customize and open **Properties Window** (you can open it by right clicking label and select properties / `View > Properties Window` / `Ctrl+W, P`) there you can see a property called **Font** expand it you will see other details too.
Refer following image,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on design view select properties and set whatever you want.

[image: Label Properties Font Property]